# Take the last row Group By date

Tags: sql, query-builder

I need to select content statistics group By Date.

Here example of records :

```
id cid viewCount created_at
1    1  50        31-12-2018 18:00:00
2    1  50        01-01-2019 18:00:00
3    2  50        01-01-2019 18:00:00
4    2  100       01-01-2019 19:00:00
5    2  150       01-01-2019 20:00:00
6    3  1000      01-01-2019 15:00:00
```

Need to return :

```
id cid viewCount date
1    1  50        31-12-2018
2    1  50        01-01-2019
5    2  150       01-01-2019
6    3  1000      01-01-2019
```

I tried the following code

```
        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('c');
        $qb->select('a.id as id')
           ->addSelect('COALESCE(SUM(a.viewCount),0) as viewCount')
           ->addSelect('DATE_FORMAT(a.createdAt, \'%d-%m-%Y\') as date');
           ->innerJoin('c.analytics', 'a')
           ->groupBy('c.cid')
           ->addGroupBy('date')
           ->orderBy('a.createdAt', 'ASC');
```

return:

```
id cid viewCount date
1   1  50        31-12-2018
2   1  50        01-01-2019
3   2  50        01-01-2019
4   2  100       01-01-2019
5   2  150       01-01-2019
6   3  1000      01-01-2019
```

I have tried to create a subquery :

```
        $qbLastHour = $this->createQueryBuilder('cc');
        $qbLastHour->select('MAX(DATE_FORMAT(aa.createdAt, \'%H\'))')
            ->innerJoin('cc.analytics', 'aa')
            ->where('cc.id=c.id')
            ->groupBy('cc.cid')
            ->addGroupBy('s');

        $qb->addSelect(sprintf("(%s) AS r", $qbLastHour->getDQl()));
```

But something go wrong because i dont groupBy date at the subquery.

If someone can help me. Thank you

Comment: Do not group by id.

Comment: @clinomaniac thank you for your answer i made a mistake i have edit the post.
I need to group by contentId ( cid )

Comment: What do you join on?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I select from my content and innerjoin the content analytic
on content_analytic.content_id=content.id

Comment: Ok, it is very hard to understand what the real sql question is. Why did you change the expected result so that time is included and why doesn’t the values add up?

Comment: Anyway, you need to either remove a.id from the output or add it to the group by clause

Comment: @JoakimDanielson my mistake when i have edit. i dont include the time.

Comment: I do not understand what you are trying to do. Why id 3 and 4 are missing in what you need ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

Here is an attempt, in sql again, to select only one row per date and `cid` based on the max time per day

```
SELECT id, c.cid, viewCount, max_date
FROM content a
JOIN content_analytic c ON a.id = c.content_id
RIGHT JOIN (SELECT c.cid, DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%d-%m-%Y') dt, MAX(created_at) max_date
            FROM content a
            JOIN content_analytic c ON a.id = c.content_id
            GROUP BY dt, c.cid) x ON x.max_date = a.created_at and x.cid = c.cid
```

---

This is how I believe the query should be in pure sql

```
SELECT c.cid, COALESCE(SUM(a.viewCount), 0), DATEFORMAT(a.created_at, ‘%d-%m-%Y’) as date
FROM content a
INNER JOIN content_analytic c ON a.id = c.content_id
GROUP BY c.cid, date
ORDER BY date
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. You don't filter by hours ? i need the last hours for the date.

Comment: What do you mean with “filter by hours”? There is no WHERE clause in your query?

Comment: For example the id 3,4,5 of my example. Need return just the id=5

Comment: @Spawnrad And that is what my code does since a.id is not included. I assume you’re using MySql?

Comment: Oh i see im trying

Comment: @Spawnrad are you saying you don’t want to sum rows but only get the last row for each day?

Comment: No, I need to sum for each contents the last row of each days :)

Comment: @Spawnrad But the sum of one row (the last row) is the same as the value for the row?

Comment: Yes I must sum the analytics of each content (the last row). I'm trying your solution. Hope it work :)

Comment: For each days (last row of each days), i need to sum the contents analytics.

Comment: it looks like he sum all rows for the same date :(

Comment: @Spawnrad I have updated my answer with a new solution now that I think I understand the question better

Comment: thank you a lot for your time im trying your solution

Comment: I want you to thank you, your answer helped me a lot and it work very well after some little adjustement. Thanks again <3